# Padrino content_for rendering string instead of HTML

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I have a `Sinatra` app and am using `Padrino`. When I use the `content_for` helper to render content within a layout it returns it as a string instead of html.

`app.rb`

```
class CateringApp < Sinatra::Application
  register Padrino::Helpers
end
```

`layout.erb`

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <%= content_for?(:main_table) ? yield_content(:main_table) : yield %>
</div>
```

`category.erb`

```
<% content_for :main_table do %>
  <div id="name" class="row">
    "IM ALIVE"
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the result I'm getting on my browser is the literal string

```
<div id="name" class="row">
   "IM ALIVE"
</div>
```

`app.rb`

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load

require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'
require 'padrino-helpers'

class CateringApp < Sinatra::Application
  enable :protect_from_csrf
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => ENV['SESSION_SECRET']
  register Padrino::Helpers
  register Sinatra::AssetPack
end

# require all config files
Dir["./config/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
require './auth'
```

`Gemfile.lock`

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activemodel (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    backports (3.6.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    dotenv (0.11.1)
      dotenv-deployment (~> 0.0.2)
    dotenv-deployment (0.0.2)
    excon (0.39.6)
    fog (1.23.0)
      fog-brightbox
      fog-core (~> 1.23)
      fog-json
      fog-softlayer
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    fog-brightbox (0.5.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto
    fog-core (1.24.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.38)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
    fog-json (1.0.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fog-softlayer (0.3.19)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    formatador (0.2.5)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    inflecto (0.0.2)
    ipaddress (0.8.0)
    jsmin (1.0.1)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.0)
    minitest (5.4.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
      mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
    padrino-helpers (0.12.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.7)
      padrino-support (= 0.12.3)
      tilt (~> 1.4.1)
    padrino-support (0.12.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
    pg (0.17.1)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    pony (1.11)
      mail (>= 2.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    sinatra (1.4.5)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
    sinatra-activerecord (2.0.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      sinatra (~> 1.0)
    sinatra-assetpack (0.3.3)
      jsmin
      rack-test
      sinatra
      tilt (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
    sinatra-contrib (1.4.2)
      backports (>= 2.0)
      multi_json
      rack-protection
      rack-test
      sinatra (~> 1.4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sinatra-flash (0.3.0)
      sinatra (>= 1.0.0)
    sinatra-reloader (1.0)
      sinatra-contrib
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord
  carrierwave
  dotenv
  fog
  padrino-helpers
  pg
  pony
  sinatra
  sinatra-activerecord
  sinatra-assetpack
  sinatra-flash
  sinatra-reloader
```

Comment: What is the desired output? To me it looks like correct behaviour. Or do you miss the stuff from layout and category? What happens if you - for debugging purposes - remove the content_for? line from layout?

Comment: @Felix I'm getting the string '<div id="name">' etc instead of it actually rendering a div.

Comment: Looks like Padrino::Rendering is not activated for some reason. Could you provide a minimal failing project with a locked Gemfile?

Comment: @kittyminky2: Do you manage to get just the layout rendered if you exclude the content_for/yield parts from your templates?

Comment: @Felix I have other views which are rendering normally within the layout. But the `category.erb` view with the content_for block is rendering as a string and not html. I have another open question that I believe is related, having to do with my form_fors not rendering properly

Comment: @kittyminky2 can you please sketch up a **minimal** failing project so I could download or clone it and look at the problem myself? I can help you but I'm having troubles with recreating the issue. It might be more complex than just a stackoverflow FAQ format.

Comment: @ujifgc sorry i misunderstood what you were asking. minimal project with setup instructions in readme https://github.com/trinityXmontoya/demo (it includes the content_for issue as well as the other one where my form_for only renders without the = meaning I can't include html in the form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `gem 'erubis'` in your Gemfile.

Padrino::Rendering can only be activated if the corresponding gem (erubis, haml or slim) is included into the bundle and visible at the moment of requiring 'padrino-helpers'.

Comment: Adding the erubis gem just broke all my sinatra assetpack links!

Comment: You can call .html_safe on the assetpack helpers to mark them as html.